# My web server name is being exposed?

Tags: apache-http-server

I have a site and I'm getting the message below when I test the site in [www.webrankpage.com](http://www.webrankpage.com).

It seems the name of the web server is being exposed, can I do something to avoid that ?

This is the message:

> Your server signature is still on which exposes critical information
>   about your server like apache version and other core elements. Hackers
>   can use this information to find exploits in the version of software
>   that you are using.

Comment: So...ummm...[flip the switch and turn it off](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serversignature)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
ServerSignature Off
```

to your `.htaccess` file!

Answer (score 0):

Another setting to consider:

```
ServerTokens ProductOnly
```

And

```
expose_php Off
```

in php.ini if you run a php enabled web server.

Don't forget to restart the daemon for changes to take effect